# How to center an input field in HTML / CSS / Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the pomodoro project on free code camp:

https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-pomodoro-clock

And I'm trying to center my input boxes but I am not achieving much success. Does anyone have any ideas?

```js
    var timeMin = 0;
    var timeSec = 3;
    var timerIntervalID = null;

    function pad (str, max) {
      str = str.toString();
      return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }


    function updateTimer() {
     var displayString = "";

     console.log("Update timer()");
     if (timeSec === 0) {
      timeSec = 59;
      timeMin--;
     } else {
      timeSec--;
     }

     displayString = timeMin + ":" + pad(timeSec, 2);


     $(".timer").html(displayString);

     if (timeMin < 1 && timeSec < 1) {
      $(".timer").css('color', 'red');
      clearInterval(timerIntervalID);
      alert("Pomodoro Over!")
     }
    }

    function test() {
     console.log("Test");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("button").click(function() {
      var whichButton = $(this).attr("value");
      console.log("Button pressed");
      switch(whichButton) {
       case "start":
        timerIntervalID = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
        break;
       case "reset":
        timeMin = 0;
        timeSec = 3;
        if (timerIntervalID !== null) {
         clearInterval(timerIntervalID);
        }

        $(".timer").css('color', 'black');
        displayString = timeMin + ":" + pad(timeSec, 2);
        $(".timer").html(displayString);
        break;
      }
     });
    });
```

```css
    .btn-primary {
     width: 15rem;
     margin: 0.2rem;
     height: 5rem;
    }

    .btn-danger {
     width: 15rem;
     margin: 0.2rem;
     height: 5rem;
    }

    input {
            max-width: 4rem;
            text-align:center;
            display:block;
            margin:0;
     }
```

```html
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>fccPomodoro</title>
     </head>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>fccPomodoro</h1>
              <h2 class="timer">Time Left: 25 minutes</h2>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="start">Start Pomodoro</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="reset">Reset</button>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="min">Minutes:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min" value="25">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sec">Seconds:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec" value="00">
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </html>
```

```
styles.css

.btn-primary {
    width: 15rem;
    margin: 0.2rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

.btn-danger {
    width: 15rem;
    margin: 0.2rem;
    height: 5rem;
}

input {
        max-width: 4rem;
        text-align:center;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
margin: 0 auto
```

on the input boxes:

```
input {
    max-width: 4rem;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See CSS below;

```js
    var timeMin = 0;
    var timeSec = 3;
    var timerIntervalID = null;

    function pad (str, max) {
      str = str.toString();
      return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
    }


    function updateTimer() {
     var displayString = "";

     console.log("Update timer()");
     if (timeSec === 0) {
      timeSec = 59;
      timeMin--;
     } else {
      timeSec--;
     }

     displayString = timeMin + ":" + pad(timeSec, 2);


     $(".timer").html(displayString);

     if (timeMin < 1 && timeSec < 1) {
      $(".timer").css('color', 'red');
      clearInterval(timerIntervalID);
      alert("Pomodoro Over!")
     }
    }

    function test() {
     console.log("Test");
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("button").click(function() {
      var whichButton = $(this).attr("value");
      console.log("Button pressed");
      switch(whichButton) {
       case "start":
        timerIntervalID = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
        break;
       case "reset":
        timeMin = 0;
        timeSec = 3;
        if (timerIntervalID !== null) {
         clearInterval(timerIntervalID);
        }

        $(".timer").css('color', 'black');
        displayString = timeMin + ":" + pad(timeSec, 2);
        $(".timer").html(displayString);
        break;
      }
     });
    });
```

```css
    .btn-primary {
     width: 15rem;
     margin: 0.2rem;
     height: 5rem;
    }

    .btn-danger {
     width: 15rem;
     margin: 0.2rem;
     height: 5rem;
    }

    .form-group {
            text-align:center;
     } 

    .form-group input {
            max-width: 4rem;
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto 0 auto;
     }
```

```html
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>fccPomodoro</title>
     </head>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>fccPomodoro</h1>
              <h2 class="timer">Time Left: 25 minutes</h2>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="start">Start Pomodoro</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="reset">Reset</button>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="min">Minutes:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="min" value="25">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sec">Seconds:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec" value="00">
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to code the input tag inside a center tag?

```
<center><input type="text" ></center>
```