# How to center an input field in HTML / CSS / Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

Just I want to share some basic question I have that I was not able to find anywhere about CSS and Bootstrap.

Basically I need to center an input text but I cannot do it. I was able to center the input box but then, the verification is not appearing in the right please. Can you please help me out?

PS1: it needs to be fully responsive.
PS2: I checked [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944626/how-to-center-an-input-field-in-html-css-bootstrap), but something else is happening at a higher css level.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Provide jsfiddle...

Comment: Hi, I tried to provide the jsfiddle but it is not formatting all the website. It is showing some JS issues. That is way I provided the website.

Comment: Then post just your html code, I will style it and center...

Comment: Hi Kind!I just changed to "col-md-12" and it solved the issue. THANKS ANYWAY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `col-md-8` to a `col-md-12` it will span the full width of the form box you're using but it will be in the centre.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't spot any misalignment. It looks great (Chrome). Do you mean the typed text inside the box?

Then add

```
text-align:center;
```

to the input field.

Comment: Hi Frank, I tried that but didn't work because bootstrap was having a higer css style. However, just changing to "col-md-12" as Carlo said, solved the problem. Thanks anyway man!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'float:left' property of the parent div of the below input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" data-bv-stringlength="true" data-bv-stringlength-min="5" required="" data-bv-field="code">
```

Comment: Thanks Deep! I just changing to "col-md-12" and problem solved.